# Calculated column with nested IFs (more than 7)

Tags: calculated-column-formula

I have calculated column for custom IDs with code:

```
=IF([ID-Type]="Hema",
IF([External-ID-Hema]>999,CONCATENATE("18",[External-ID-Hema]),
IF([External-ID-Hema]>99,CONCATENATE("180",[External-ID-Hema]),
IF([External-ID-Hema]>9,CONCATENATE("1800",[External-ID-Hema]),
CONCATENATE("18000",[External-ID-Hema])))),

IF([ID-Type]="GeboCermex",
IF([External-ID-Gebo]>999,CONCATENATE("19",[External-ID-Gebo]),
IF([External-ID-Gebo]>99,CONCATENATE("190",[External-ID-Gebo]),
IF([External-ID-Gebo]>9,CONCATENATE("1900",[External-ID-Gebo]),
CONCATENATE("19000",[External-ID-Gebo]))))))
```

It works fine...

But when I will add more IF's

```
&IF([ID-Type]="External",
IF([External-ID-Ext]>999,CONCATENATE("25",[External-ID-Ext]),
IF([External-ID-Ext]>99,CONCATENATE("250",[External-ID-Ext]),
IF([External-ID-Ext]>9,CONCATENATE("2500",[External-ID-Ext]),
CONCATENATE("25000",[External-ID-Ext])))))
```

Then all previous values are with prefix/suffix FALSE eg.: 190004FALSE, FALSE250000 (numbers are fine, just this "FALSE" is added)

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: UPDATE: if I will replace "&IF" by "+IF" then FALSE will be removed but.... unfortunately numbers will be with coma eg.:  100,004; 250,000

Answer (score 1):

You can only have 7 nested IF levels...

I have not tested it, but at first sight

```
    IF([External-ID-Hema]>999,CONCATENATE("18",[External-ID-Hema]),
       IF([External-ID-Hema]>99,CONCATENATE("180",[External-ID-Hema]),
          IF([External-ID-Hema]>9,CONCATENATE("1800",[External-ID-Hema])
             ,CONCATENATE("18000",[External-ID-Hema])
            )
         )
       )
```

can be replaced with:

```
"18"  &  TEXT( [External-ID-Hema] , "0000" )
```

https://www.365csi.nl/vm365com/365coach/#/Calculated_Column_Functions_List

That means your complete Formula would be ***something like*:**

```
IF (           [ID-Type]="Hema"       , "18" & TEXT( [External-ID-Hema] , "0000") 
    , IF (     [ID-Type]="GeboCermex" , "19" & TEXT( [External-ID-Gebo] , "0000") 
        , IF ( [ID-Type]="External"   , "25" & TEXT( [External-ID-Ext]  , "0000")
             , ""
            )
    )
)
```

You are still bound by 7 nested IFs, so a maximum of 7 products with this syntax, and need more Calculated Columns (or nested IFs *inside* nested IFs) to split your logic for over 7 products

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround to  "**+IF**" is to add another column which will be calculated on my "main" with formula "=TEXT([My_CustomID_column],"0") which will convert number 190,004 to 190004.

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention to parentheses - current formatting is misleading. Here's how it's really parsed: [image]

Try this:

```
=IF([ID-Type]="Hema",
IF([External-ID-Hema]>999,CONCATENATE("18",[External-ID-Hema]),
IF([External-ID-Hema]>99,CONCATENATE("180",[External-ID-Hema]),
IF([External-ID-Hema]>9,CONCATENATE("1800",[External-ID-Hema]),
CONCATENATE("18000",[External-ID-Hema])))),

IF([ID-Type]="GeboCermex",
IF([External-ID-Gebo]>999,CONCATENATE("19",[External-ID-Gebo]),
IF([External-ID-Gebo]>99,CONCATENATE("190",[External-ID-Gebo]),
IF([External-ID-Gebo]>9,CONCATENATE("1900",[External-ID-Gebo]),
CONCATENATE("19000",[External-ID-Gebo])))),

IF([ID-Type]="External",
IF([External-ID-Ext]>999,CONCATENATE("25",[External-ID-Ext]),
IF([External-ID-Ext]>99,CONCATENATE("250",[External-ID-Ext]),
IF([External-ID-Ext]>9,CONCATENATE("2500",[External-ID-Ext]),
CONCATENATE("25000",[External-ID-Ext])))))))
```

Comment: Edited. Should be OK now, but it's just unmaintainable. @Danny is right, this should be refactored ASAP